# How to reverse a triangle jagged array?

Tags: java, arrays

I have already done with normal jagged array, but I don't understand how to reverse it upside down. Also I have a question, how to shift the side of triangle from left side to right? Can I do this with loops or I need to write different quantity of whitespaces for every line of my array?

```
static int[][] triangle(int lines){
    int[][] arr = new int[lines][];
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        arr[i] = new int[i + 1];
    }
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++){
            arr[i][j] = count++;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++){
            System.out.print(arr[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
return arr;
}
```

Some kind of result:

```
0 
1 2 
3 4 5 
6 7 8 9 
10 11 12 13 14
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can quickly create a reversed triangle by changing the way you initialize your `arr` array.

```
static int[][] revTriangle(int lines) {
    int[][] arr = new int[lines][];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = new int[lines - i]; // this line
    }
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = count++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    return arr;
}
```

I get the following output:

```
0 1 2 3 4 
5 6 7 8 
9 10 11 
12 13 
14
```

---

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you need a more compact solution you can group some loops (basing on anacron answer):

```
  static int[][] triangle( int lines, boolean straight)
  {
    int[][] arr = new int[lines][];
    int count = 0;    
    for ( int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ )
    {
      int start = (straight? i : lines);
      int step = (straight? 1 : -i);
      arr[i] = new int[start + step ];
      for ( int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++ )
      {
        arr[i][j] = count++;
        System.out.print( arr[i][j] + " " );        
      }
      System.out.println();
    }    
return arr;
```

}